# lsusb shows "rt3572" but lshw shows "generic 2800" driver after installing the latest ralink

Tags: 12.04, drivers

I have a quick question. I just got the ae1000 linksys usb wifi card. I installed the latest drivers from ralink (rt3572). Now, when I use "lsusb" I see "Linksys AE1000 v1 802.11n [Ralink RT3572]. When I use "lshw" I see "driver=rt2800usb" on wireless 802.11abgn.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought I should be seeing  the same rt3572 number on hw and usb.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RT3572 is the chipset made by ralink, inside the AE1000. The RT3572 chipset is supported (sort of...*) by the RT2800 driver, which also supports many other flavors of ralink chipsets.

- Note that this driver is notoriously buggy. Follow the build and install instructions explicitly. Which version of the driver you should use is highly dependent on which kernel version you are using, among other things. The latest version of the driver software is not necessarily the one that will work on your system. Some web searching for the appropriate driver version to work with your kernel may be required.

Comment: Thanks Warren. I've noticed that the 2800 driver is very buggy. I was hopping to be able to update it.So, I went to ralink's website and downloaded the last driver they have for the rt3572 (which in theory should fit my ae1000's chipset). I've followed their instructions and I've managed to install the rt3572 driver without errors, but I still see the 2800 on "lshw". Does that mean I didn't install it properly? I have also noticed that the ae1000 gets disconnected at times (especially when the computer was sleeping for a while) it shots itself off and I have to unplug it to make it work again.